# Mass flux across a volume

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image]

Here mass flux means the mass flow rate, units: kilograms/second

**This is for a one-dimensional flow**

Firstly is the reason why the mass flux/ mass flow rate $=$

$\rho(x_1,t)A(x_1,t)u(x_1,t)$ because

mass flux/ mass flow rate $=\rho(x_1,t)\vec{A}(x_1,t)\vec{u}(x_1,t)$ has unit normal of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{u}$ pointing in the same direction?

Even so I don't really conceptually understand why the mass flux/mass flow rate **into** the arbitrary volume BCDE is given by

$\rho(x_1,t)\vec{A}(x_1,t)\vec{u}(x_1,t)$

Comment: Please transcribe pictures of texts into proper LaTeX, if possible.

Comment: Note that [cross-posting between Stack Exchange sites](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1209239/87420) is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Ok, where am I more likely to get an answer to this sort of fluid dynamics question?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really conceptually understand why the mass flux/mass flow rate into the arbitrary volume BCDE is given by [...]

$u$ is speed. This is a distance per second. Multiply a distance (per second) with a cross-section area, and you get volume (per second). So

$$\dot V=Au$$

where the dot in $\dot V$ simply means *per second*. If some particles of water are just outside the area $A$, then after one second a total volume of $V$ have passed through this area and into the volume next to.

From here it should be fairly easy to grasp that multiplying a volume (per second) $\dot V$ with the density $\rho$ gives the total mass (per second) $\dot m$. That is: The number of cubic meters entering the volume next to the cross-section every second *times* the mass of each cubic meter equals the total mass entering every second:

$$\dot m=\rho \dot V=\rho A u$$

This $\dot m$ is what is called *mass flow rate* or *mass flux*.

**Addition:**
That your variables are symbolized as $\rho(x,t)$, $A(x,t)$ and $u(x,t)$ simply says that these might not be constant but vary with both time and position. Same calculation holds, but the variables themselves might be a bit more complex to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $\vec u(\vec r, t)$ is the vector field describing the velocity of the fluid.

The flux, generally, will be of the form $\rho \vec A \cdot \vec u$. $\rho(\vec r, t)$ gives us the amount of mass that is flowing at $(\vec r, t)$, $\vec u$ gives us its velocity, and $\vec A$ gives us the area through which it is flowing, so it makes sense that we need to multiply these together in some fashion to generate the flux. However, we still haven't said anything about the direction of the flow relative to the area. This is clearly important: if $\vec u$ is parallel to the surface $A$ (perpendicular to $\vec A$), then there is no flux at all, while if $\vec u$ is perpendicular to the surface A (parallel to $\vec A$), then there is maximum flux; we expect that this will vary smoothly as $\vec u$ points more and more into $A$. Sinc the dot product gives the product of the parallel components of two vectors, it accounts for this directional issue by picking out the part of $\vec u$ that points into $A$ (parallel to $\vec A$) and contributes to the flux, while discarding the part of $\vec u$ that points parallel to $A$ (perpendicular to $\vec A$) and does not contribute to the flux. Therefore the flux is $\Phi = \rho \vec A \cdot \vec u$.

Now, why $x_1$? Think about the breakdown of the volume into little slices $A$. If the fluid flows out of one slice, it flows into the next, thereby not contributing to the flux, unless the slice is the last slice, i.e., at $x_2$. If the fluid flows into one slice, it flows out of the previous, thereby also not contributing to the flux, unless the slice is the first slice, i.e., at $x_1$. Therefore, the flux into the whole volume is just that into the first slice, $\Phi_\mathrm{into \,\, volume} = \Phi(x_1,t) = \rho(x_1,t) \vec A(x_1,t) \cdot \vec u(x_1,t)$.

Note that what's on the piece of paper isn't entirely correct in that this **does not** work for an arbitrary volume: it assumes that the cross-sectional areas $A$ are the same. To see this, consider a half-ball with the curved half pointing directly into the flow and the flat half pointing directly with the flow. There is clearly a nonzero flux into the volume, but since the first slice is just one point, $|\vec A(x_1,t)| = 0$, so the formula must give the wrong result. Similarly, since $\rho$ and $\vec u$ are specified only in terms of the $x$ coordinate, they must be constant in the $y$ and $z$ directions, so this only works for such flows.

Comment: Why are we able to think about there being a 3D slice at $x_1$, when $x_1$ is just a point. Wouldn't any slice at $x_1$ be 2 dimensional?

Comment: This is surprisingly subtle. It's a foundational issue in calculus. The usual way we think about this is of an infinitesimally thin slice from $x_1$ to $x_1+\delta$, for infinitesimally small $\delta$. This is sort of just a crutch for our reasoning, though, in formulation of integration as the limit of a Riemann sum as the number of terms goes to inifinity and the width of each little rectangle in the sum goes to 0. A better interpretation is that the flow into the volume is the same as the flow into the boundary of the volume, which is, indeed, 2-dimensional; a 3D slice is unnecessary.